# char *test[]. What does it means this structure?

Tags: c++, arrays, char, c-strings, definition

Example:
//
test.h

```
#define MAX 3
```

test.cpp

```
static char *movies[MAX] = {
    "The Departed", "The Crow", "Hot Fuzz"};
```

//

Why not use Vector<char*>, or Vector<string*>, or an Array, or another data type?
What benefits do i have over the other data types?

Let me preface this by saying that i'm coming from the Java world andi've been learning C++ for a few months.

Comment: Perhaps a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) might help.

Comment: Strictly speaking this isn't valid code, it should be `static const char *movies[MAX]` since string literals are immutable

Comment: That seems more like C than C++. Where did you see that code? From where did you get it?

Comment: This is an array, making the part about "an array, or another data type" confusing

Comment: Also note that `Vector<string*>` is wrong. Not only in captialization but also the contained type. It should be `vector<string>` (or `std::vector<std::string>` if you don't do `using namespace std;` which is [a bad habit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)).

Comment: Also, C++ and Java are quite different languages, despite the fact they have some superficial similarities of syntax.   Trying to learn C++ by using Java as a starting point will make you a terrible C++ developer (the reverse is also true - learning Java by using C++ as a starting point would make you a terrible Java developer).   If you want to learn C++, get a C++ book, and ignore what you know from Java, because most of it is wrong in C++.

Answer (score 0):

> What benefits do i have over the other data types?

One thing to notice if using `std::vector` is that it will be initialized dynamically at runtime while the `static const char*[max]` can be initialized at compile time. So it will save some(very little though) runtime.

Comment: Not always "very little". It involves memory allocation which generally is to be avoided when not needed.

Answer (score -1):

You will not have to directly cast the pointer to another type.. if some functions only accept the char ptr vector then you will not have any conversion to do

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).